# Sort rows and columns by given vector

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I can't find a way to sort a matrix by a given order. I have an n x m matrix with names assigned to rows and columns. I also have two vectors that contain my ordering. I want to reorder rows and columns according to the two vectors I have.

This is my code:

```
tab<-read.csv("matrix.csv",sep="\t",header=T,row.names=1,check.names=FALSE)
mat<-as.matrix(tab)
```

`sorted` contains the column order I want,
`sorted2` contains the row order I want.

`mat` has row names and column names that are a subset of `sorted` and `sorted2`

I tried `order()` but I can't figure out how to specify column wise, row wise orderings.

Comment: can you dput your different variable and respect the posting chart? Cheers :)

Comment: I think I figured it out, it should be mat[sorted2[which(sorted2 %in% rownames(mat))],sorted[which(sorted %in% colnames(mat))]]

Answer (score 1):

```
## Generate data

set.seed(1)

dat <- matrix(round(rnorm(4, 5), 2), 2)

## Define order

Vec1 <- c(1, 2)

Vec2 <- c(2, 1)

# Sort columns

dat[order(Vec1),]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.37 4.16
[2,] 5.18 6.60

dat[order(Vec2),]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 5.18 6.60
[2,] 4.37 4.16

# Sort rows

dat[,order(Vec1)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.37 4.16
[2,] 5.18 6.60

dat[,order(Vec2)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.16 4.37
[2,] 6.60 5.18
```